# Nokia Imaging SDK problems with EditingSession Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am trying to learn the Nokia Imaging SDK by going through the examples at developer.nokia.com and several other sites. 
Most of the examples tell to use this EditingSession class which is a part of Nokia Imaging SDK. But when I'm trying to use it I get the following error.

> The type or namespace name 'EditingSession' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

[image]

I have included all the libraries correctly through NuGet Packages. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the documentation/examples you are looking at? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking at the old version of the documentation, while using the new (1.0) version of the Nokia Imaging SDK.

If I remember correctly EditingSession was important in the previous, BETA, versions of the SDK. The previous versions (and examples, documentation, etc) are **not compatible** with the 1.0 release, as it introduced several breaking changes.

Try looking at the new [Quick Start](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!nokia-imaging-sdk/quick-start.html) and work your way from there.

Comment: thanks for the link. the new examples work perfectly.