# Nokia imaging SDK editingsession is not found -windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

Im new to nokia image SDK, I ahve installed the latest version(1.0.272.0 ) for windows phone .Whenever I try to use EditingSession, I get error as

> "EditingSession is not found.Are you missing an assembly directive?"

I have included the following namespace

```
using Nokia.Graphics.Imaging;
using Nokia.InteropServices;
```

Please help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nokia Imaging SDK problems with EditingSession Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174638/nokia-imaging-sdk-problems-with-editingsession-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image SDK has changed significantly in the RTM version (compared to Beta versions) and in RTM, editing session is gone. With a lot of samples around are still referring to beta code, you can take a look at differences between Beta and RTM versions here (http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!nokia-imaging-sdk/how-to-upgrade.html) or consult RTM core concepts at Nokia's Imaging SDK site (http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!nokia-imaging-sdk/core-concepts.html).